# Why does the exponential distribution's pdf integrate to 1?

Tags: exponential-function

From *All of Statistics* pg. 29:

> **EXPONENTIAL DISTRIBUTION.** $X$ has an Exponential distribution with paramater $\beta$, denoted by $X \sim \text{Exp}(\beta)$, if
>
> $$
> f(x) = \frac{1}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta} \text{s.t. } x > 0
> $$
>
> where $\beta > 0$. The exponential distribution is used to model the lifetimes of electronic components and the waiting times between rare events.

But this must mean (in order for the probability density function to make sense) that

$$
1/\beta \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x / \beta} = 1
$$

so that

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x / \beta} = \beta
$$

But why is this?

Comment: Last equation should be $\beta$ not $1/\beta$.

Comment: @jdods: corrected.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/918603/215011 , which uses $\lambda$ in place of $1/\beta$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, 
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x/\beta}\;dx=\int_0^{\infty}d\left(-\beta e^{-x/\beta}\right)=\left.-\beta e^{-x/\beta}\right|_0^{\infty}$$
$$= \lim_{R\to\infty}\left.-\beta e^{-x/\beta}\right|_0^R=\lim_{R\to\infty}(-\beta e^{-R/\beta}-(-\beta))$$
$$=0+\beta = \beta$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}x}=-\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}x}.$$

So that 
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}x}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left[-e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}x}\right]_0^t
=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left(-e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}t}+1\right)=1.$$

This is an improper integral, which is why the limit procedure is necessary. The exponential decays to zero as $t\rightarrow\infty$ since $\beta>0.$